# Get a specific session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis

On my `Global.asax` I store all the session ids. If I have the session Id `Foo` how can I get a speciffic value for that particular session and **NOT** the current session.

In other words I want to do something like

```
HttpContext.GetSessionById("Foo").Session["LoggedInUserId"];
```

instead of

```
HttpContext.Current.Sesssion["LoggedInUserId"];
```

Comment: Where do you store those `Session` Objects? I would suggest an Extension Method. But Added to that `.Session[".."]`. It makes thing complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your application and you are not just trying to hijack a session, why not store this info in a database?  You can then query the session info in the database by the ID and get what you want.

Comment: You should put it as a comment. Otherwise you will receive downovote as it is not an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is "an answer".  I'm not going to code it up for the lad.

Comment: It makes no sence to create a new table just because on one operation on my webservice it takes a long time to complete. And if I use a session it will slow down all the requests from that client until that method complets. As a result I do not want to use a session on that method. Saving the session data on the database will be a solution but I think it is too much work just because of one method

Comment: You will have to give more info on what the heck you are trying to accomplish here.  Perhaps you can post the code of your webservice and we can help speed up the performance.

Comment: I guess there is no way to get a different session other than the current so I will create that table and accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you.  This is efficient and gives you a trail you can always follow.  You may want to consider purging this table by date because I'm sure the info becomes not useful after some period of time and you don't want to be querying millions of records if you don't have to.